# Initialize nested interface - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to initialize a nested interface.

This is how my model file looks like:

```
export interface ICar {
    color: string;
    number: string;
    type: array<IType>;
} 

export interface IType{ 
    big: string;
    small: string;
    boat: array<IboatType>;
}

export interface IboatType{
    value: string;
    winter: string;
}
```

Now in my component file I try to initialize it:

```
let car: ICar= {
  type: {
    boat: {
        value: "test";
        winter: "yolo";
    }

  }

}
```

this does not work, I tried to check online but I have not found anything.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because all of your properties are required in order to create an object from the interface you provided.

You have some syntax errors such as:

1. Your array should be uppercase A
2. You are missing some array brackets

If you want to make some of the properties optional you have to declare them as optional in your interface file:

The typescript book explains all this in details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

So you would have something like

```
export interface ICar {
  color?: string;
  number?: string;
  type?: Array<IType>;
}

export interface IType {
  big?: string;
  small?: string;
  boat?: Array<IboatType>;
}

export interface IboatType {
  value: string;
  winter: string;
}

export const car: ICar = {
  type: [{
    boat: [{
      value: "test";
      winter: "yolo";
    }]
  }]
}
```